# How to view relationships between classes as a visual diagram?

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea, diagram

when joining an existing project it can become confusing trying to figure out how all the classes and interfaces are connected to each other. Instead of going to individual classes and following its relationships, is there a way to visually see all the connections in a diagram? Is there anything that can be done in IntelliJ(11 | 12) or Visual Studio(2010 | 2012 - preferably express or pro)?

For example, something like a UML diagram showing class A inherits from class B which extends a certain interface, etc.

Similar functionality is in Eclipse where you can view a graphical representation of a bean config file. Also in Visual Studio you can view the DB relationships

Comment: http://www.screenr.com/JSas

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder that is exactly what I'm looking for :), the only thing is that the video appears to skip the part of getting the diagram - then suddenly has the end result.

Comment: Refer to help: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/diagrams.html .

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks man. It appears that I need the ultimate version :( Anyway, have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what version of Visual studio you are using but in VS 2012 pro (Update 2) you can right click on a project and click the "View Class Diagram" option. This will Create a diagram of all classes in the project.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x35cds6.aspx

Looks like capability goes as far back and 2010 and even 2008.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if it was at all possible in any of the versions. I will update the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

this is old but it's magical in VS2019. right click on project solution or any classes
you want to see dependencies and hit "Show Type Dependency Diagram".

[image]

Comment: Is it part of extension or was it removed in VS22?